# Debugging Mongoid and Sunspot SOLR

Tags: solr, mongoid, sunspot-rails

I am fiddling with sunspot and SOLR sunspot, trough [sunspot mongoid](https://github.com/jugyo/sunspot_mongoid). Everything seems to work fine, but I am not getting search results back.

The solr admin on http://0.0.0.0:8982/solr/admin/ tells me that there are items indexed, though I have too little knowledge to interprete the exact indexes there. Also, searching through that interface does not give me results either.

I am rather new to SOLR: I have implemented it successfully with a "generic" active-record/mysql Rails app in the past; but not with mongoID.

The problem might be anywhere: not correctly indexed, not correctly retrieved, not correctly passed trough sunspot and so on.

Is it a good idea to start at the solr side first? Throw some requests over HTTP to it, to see if it is actually indexing stuff? If so, how?
Or should I fiddle in rails first, see if it is getting some XML back but parsing or interpreting it wrong?

Comment: if you go to the analysis, put the Field as <your_field_name>_text, like country_name_text if your column is country_name. Check all boxes, and click Analyze.What do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was having the same problem, and I also noticed that it wouldn't reindex my results.  Then I found the [sunspot_mongo](https://github.com/balexand/sunspot_mongo) gem. Use it instead of `sunspot_mongoid`

In your gemfile

`gem 'sunspot_mongo'`

Then in your models

`include Sunspot::Mongo`

Then instead of calling search in your controllers do:

```
Model.solr_search do
  fulltext params[:q]
end
```

Also, to reindex do `rake sunspot:mongo:reindex`

I think `rake sunspot:reindex` just tries to index your sqlite database that your probably not using.

Comment: that is `include Sunspot::Mongo`, not sunspot:mongo